# Android tablelayout click listener for cell content

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I have a 3x3 gridview with custom linearlayouts within. But I want something like this
[layout](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/android-tablelayout-demo1.png) and as I search on the internet it's not possible with gridview because of the column span. I used gridview because of the onClickListener method: when the user click on one of the grid cell, a new activity starts(not the same activity, so it's like a main menu). Is it possible to do in a TableLayout? So if I click on a cell even if it spanned can I call an onClick method? I've searched the web for some solutions, but all of what I've found is clicking on a tablerow(which is not good for me if there is 3 custom layouts in one row).

My layout for the TableLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerPicture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageString"
    android:src="@drawable/bicaj" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/mainFirstRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainOnline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainIconOnline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/main_page_icon_descp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainTextOnline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
.
.
.
.
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want clickListeners for each and every view in TableLayout??

Comment: Yes, if I click e.g on the second row's second column's item it should start a new activity. But if I click on the e.g on the third row's third column's item it should start another activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `clickListeners` to the `ImageView`

```
.....
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainOnline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mainIconOnline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/main_page_icon_descp" />
......
```

And in your Activity

```
ImageView butt1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainIconOnline);

        butt1.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.mainIconOnline) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivityclass);
        startActivity(i);

        }

    }
```

This should work

Comment: Okay, thank's I give it a try. If it works, I will mark as an answer : )